# Mongo DB pool connection error

Tags: java, mongodb, dbconnection, mongo-java

I am using mongoDb with java. I am getting the following error while inserting data. Any help would be appreciated. Thanx

```
Jul 4, 2012 1:45:32 PM org.xsocket.connection.HandlerAdapter performOnData
WARNING: [6f829b013850ff7914137a5cceC291] closing connection. Error occured by performing onData of com.avaya.onex.hss.requesthandlers.ResponseHandler#18746603 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Jul 4, 2012 1:45:25 PM com.mongodb.DBPortPool gotError
WARNING: emptying DBPortPool to localhost:27017 b/c of error
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
    at org.bson.io.PoolOutputBuffer.pipe(PoolOutputBuffer.java:129)
    at com.mongodb.OutMessage.pipe(OutMessage.java:111)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:119)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:89)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.say(DBPort.java:84)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.say(DBTCPConnector.java:153)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.say(DBTCPConnector.java:138)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:261)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:211)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:57)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:102)
    at com.avaya.onex.hss.requesthandlers.DatabaseConnection.dbWrite(DatabaseConnection.java:50)
    at com.avaya.onex.hss.requesthandlers.ResponseHandler.handleResponse(ResponseHandler.java:232)
    at com.avaya.onex.hss.requesthandlers.ResponseHandler.onData(ResponseHandler.java:104)
    at org.xsocket.connection.HandlerAdapter.performOnData(HandlerAdapter.java:242)
    at org.xsocket.connection.HandlerAdapter.access$200(HandlerAdapter.java:42)
    at org.xsocket.connection.HandlerAdapter$PerformOnDataTask.run(HandlerAdapter.java:210)
    at org.xsocket.SerializedTaskQueue.performPendingTasks(SerializedTaskQueue.java:161)
    at org.xsocket.SerializedTaskQueue.access$100(SerializedTaskQueue.java:40)
    at org.xsocket.SerializedTaskQueue$MultithreadedTaskProcessor.run(SerializedTaskQueue.java:189)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

This is the class where I have dbWrite function which I call from other classes for inserting data in mongodb.

```
package com.avaya.onex.hss.requesthandlers;

import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.Mongo;
import com.mongodb.MongoOptions;
import com.mongodb.WriteConcern;

public class DatabaseConnection {
    private static DatabaseConnection con = null;
    static DB db=null;
    static Mongo m;
    //private static int count=0;

    private DatabaseConnection(){
    }

    public void dbConnect() {

        try{
        // connect to the local database server
        MongoOptions options = new MongoOptions();
        options.connectionsPerHost = 9000000;
        options.maxWaitTime = 1000000;
        options.socketKeepAlive = true;
        options.threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier = 1000;

         m = new Mongo("localhost", options);

         //m.dropDatabase("ClientSimulator");
         db = m.getDB( "ClientSimulator" );

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static synchronized DatabaseConnection getInstanceClass(){
        if(con==null)
            con=new DatabaseConnection();
        return con;
    }

    public DB getDatabaseObject(){
        return db;
    }

    public synchronized void dbWrite(DBCollection coll, BasicDBObject obj){
        coll.insert(obj);
        try {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void dbRead(DBCollection coll){
    }

    public synchronized void dbUpdate(DBCollection coll) {
    }

    public synchronized void dbCollDrop(DBCollection coll){
        coll.drop();
    }
}
```

Comment: it seems that your connection dropped. is mongo running?

Comment: what's in the server log at the time this happens?

Comment: Wed Jul 04 11:56:57 [initandlisten] can't create new thread, closing connection
Wed Jul 04 11:58:31 [PeriodicTask::Runner] task: DBConnectionPool-cleaner took:
62ms
Wed Jul 04 11:58:31 [PeriodicTask::Runner] task: WriteBackManager::cleaner took
 46ms

Comment: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Are you running it in a VM?

Comment: eclipse for java.. i even set the VM arguments in it. I have set it to -Xmx1500m (1500MB).... as i have only 2GB RAM...

Comment: Can you post the code inserting data? My guess is that it doesn't automatically close the connection. If you're using that much memory, I'd say you're doing something wrong. You should be able to stream anything to Mongodb with less that 64mb. Even inserting big files in mongodb is possible since every BSON objects can't be bigger than 4mb by default.

Comment: I have added the code in the post.. U can see that now..

Comment: Seems like everything is fine there. And what does mongodb put in the logs when the connection is dropped?

Comment: Wed Jul 04 11:56:57 [initandlisten] can't create new thread, closing connection Wed Jul 04 11:58:31 [PeriodicTask::Runner] task: DBConnectionPool-cleaner took: 62ms Wed Jul 04 11:58:31 [PeriodicTask::Runner] task: WriteBackManager::cleaner took 46ms

Comment: Not sure how do you run your program but mongodb seems to receive a lots of Connections. In your options, you have 9000000 max connections. You might want to reduce that number and try again. You might also reduce the max wait time. It's possible that your program tries to connect at most that number of connection for each insert if a connection is used and won't wait that time to use a free connection.

Comment: What version of the java driver are you using? There have been severalenhancements made to the latest version, 2.8.0, I would recommend upgrading and then re-testing.

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

```
    options.connectionsPerHost = 100;
    options.maxWaitTime = 2000;
    options.socketKeepAlive = true;
    options.threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier = 50;
```

connectionsPerHost is the connectionPool. If you put 9000000 it will try to create 90000000 threads and connection object to handle your request. I believe that it is by far more than necessary. You have to reduce that number, and you might also remove the sleep(100) in your insert function.

If java tries to create that many connections. Mongodb server might not be able to handle that much connection or you'd have to change the config to allow that much connections.

Keep in mind that connectionsPerHost is not the maximum quantity of threads. You could have 1000000 threads inserting but only 100 connections will be used and will be shared for all the threads once they are free. maxWaitTime of 2 second should be more than enough. If an insert takes more than 2 seconds, you might consider upgrading your server.

Comment: why do you need a wait time of 2 hours? you have really slow requests?

Answer (score 1):

Driver can't remove dropped socket from connection from pool, you need use try catch to let the driver know the socket is dropped.